# Como alterar o valor do href de um link, filtrando pelo nome do link?

Tags: javascript

Exemplo:
Tenho uma lista de links:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Nome1</a>
  </li>
    <a href="#">Nome2</a>
  </li>
    <a href="#">Nome3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Queria fazer algum filtro em JS que trocasse o valor do href apenas do "nome2" por exemplo.

Já procurei em alguns lugares, mas infelizmente não achei

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Seleciona todos os elementos que deseja filtrar e faz uma comparação com o texto.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
   if(links[i].textContent == 'Nome2')
   {
      links[i].href = '#novo_link';
   }
}
```

Nesse exemplo eu utilizei `document.getElementsByTagName("a");` que irá selecionar todas as tags `a` do html.

Mas caso voce não queira que o filtro se aplique a todas as tags, voce pode limitar utilizando classes e utilizar `getElementsByClassName`

```
<div class="filtro">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Nome1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Nome2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Nome3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>

    var elementosComClasseFiltro = document.getElementsByClassName("filtro");

    var links = elementosComClasseFiltro[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
        if(links[i].textContent == 'Nome2'){
        links[i].href = '#novo_link';
        }
    }

</script>
```

perceba que `elementosComClasseFiltro` é uma coleção, entao eu apliquei o filtro apenas no primeiro elemento que foi encontrado no html.

Comment: Show de bola! Era exatamente o que eu queria.

Comment: Tem como limitar só a class de uma div, como você fez no segundo exemplo?
É que é uma página no Wordpress e eu não consigo adicionar classes nos links. Eles são filhos de uma div que tem classe.

Comment: da sim, editei minha resposta

Comment: Maravilha, Marcos, funcionou perfeitamente. Me ajudou demais!
Só não entendi porque o `elementosComClasseFiltro` tem [0]

Comment: Porque ele é o resultado de todos os elementos do HTML que possui a classe com nome filtro. o método getElementsByClassName retorna um array.

Comment: Nesse código só existe um elemento com essa classe, por isso pegando a posição zero do array, já é o suficiente